# How to select the total downloads of each promotion that I have in my database, with laravel ORM eloquent 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

Using laravel, I need to show in a graph the number of times a promotion is redeemed. I can get the promotions published by each user that starts session, but I need you to put that data in a graph. I would greatly appreciate your help.

---

### Current Code:

```php
    $nombres = Promociones::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->pluck('nombre_promocion', 'id');

    $promociones = [];
    $descargadas = [];

    foreach ($nombres as $key => $val)
    {
        $promociones[] = $val;
        $descargadas[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$key)->count();
    }  

    $chart = new UserPromociones;
    $chart->title(' Promociones publicadas ');
    $chart->labels($promociones);
    $chart->dataset('Numero de promociones','bar', ($descargadas));
    $chart->dataset('Total de promociones publicadas = '.$total_promociones,'bar',[]);
```

---

### Desired Graph Output:

[image: the graph]

Comment: are you sure that `$nombres` is keyed with user id's ?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is in this line

```
$descargadas[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$key)->count();
```

as you only look for user_id who match the array index!!

it should be like

```
$descargadas[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$val)->count();
```

or

```
$descargadas[] = Promociones::where('user_id',$val->id)->count();
```

and even if this work , that is not the best way, the worst thing to do is to but and database query in loop, that is horrible

if the data is not that big , you can do something like that before foreach

```
$promociones = collect(Promociones::all()->toArray());
```

this will extract the model to a collection, then any where clause will be a search in a collection and require no database query for each time.

```
 $promociones = collect(Promociones::all()->toArray());

 foreach ($nombres as $key => $val)
    {
        $promociones[] = $val;
        $descargadas[] = $promociones->where('user_id',$val->any_filed)->count();
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your friend suggestion, they gave me an idea to solve my problem
this was the solution `$descargadas[] = Promociones::where('id',$key)->pluck('veces_cajeadas');`